# Variable called in class object when not defined?

Tags: php, class, object

I have started to really dive into other peoples code, and I hope this is considered a simple question, but something threw me off that I hope you can explain:

When reading this simple start script to a templating engine I noticed there was no define or variable set for the $variable->object.

```
class Template {
protected $file;
protected $values = array();

public function __construct($file) {
    $this->file = $file;
   }
}
```

If you notice in the basic code above, $this->file = $file, the "file" object is referenced without ever being defined.  Is it be cause of the __construct function? Or am I missing something else?  If so are all construct variables set as "define()"'s within the function?

## EDIT:

Question is, does __construct act as a define() so that "file" can be used anywhere in the code as if it were a variable $file? Or is "protected" essentially defining the the variable $file, allowing me to use the variable $file.  but if that were the case,

how come

```
function __construct($file)
```

does not look like:

```
function __construct(file) if that is the case?
```

Guess I am confused as to how "file" has been called and what part of the code defined "file"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting variables on Constructor VS on the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484265/setting-variables-on-constructor-vs-on-the-class-definition)

Comment: But generally it's possible but not clean

Comment: I have no idea what's "not defined" here. `protected $file` defines the property that `$this->file` refers to. `$file` comes into the function as an argument.

Comment: @deceze so protect $file allows for global use of "file" as long as $this->file is referenced.  My confusion is how "file" exists in the first place without being defined.  Essentially how can "file" be used?

Comment: It's **`$this->file`**, not `file`, and it refers to the previously defined `protected $file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$file` property is defined in your class :

```
class Template {
protected $file; // <-- HERE
protected $values = array();
```

Anyway, defining properties is not mandatory. In PHP, you can assign a value to an object's property even if it is not defined in the class.

However, that's an ungly way of working, and that is for two reasons :

- If you use undefined properties, their is no way for someone who looks at your class to know that such a property is used, since it is not documented.
- Defining a property allows you to specify an **access modifier** : `public` if the property must be accessible from anywhere, `private` if it must be available from the class itself only, and `protected` if it must be accessed from its class itself or any class extending it.
  If you define a property without access modifier it will be public by default. If you don't define the property at all, it will be the same, but with even less clues to figure out what is happening.

**Only use undefined properties if you intend the developers whose job will be to use or maintain your code to want to kill you, because I can garantee you they will.**

Comment: so protected in this instance acts the same way as define()?  So through the entire class I can simply type file, and the class will know to reference protected $file?

Comment: I think I got it so $this->file is essentially referencing template->file , or in other words class->variable in this instance?  and $file is set by whichever code initiates the class correct?  If this is the case, what is the need for the variable in the construct?

Comment: @DEVPROCB the `$file` passed to `__constrruct()` is used to set `$this->file`.