# In PHP OOP approach where should I set initial values in a class?

Tags: php, oop

Setting an initial value to a property is available when you declare the property. Is it a good practice or should I do it in the constructor? Or is it doesn't really matter as long I do the same way everywhere consistently?

Just to make it clear, what I'm talking about, here is an example:

```
class ClassA{
    private $propertyA;

    public function __construct(){
         $this->propertyA = "value: A";
    }
}
```

or

```
class ClassB{
    private $propertyB = "value: B";

    public function __construct(){
    }
}
```

Comment: Always set the initial values in `constructor` bcoz when you are making any object of that class then the variables are automatically initialize with default values...

Comment: If they're purely static assignments, set them in the property definition; if they're dependent on runtime information, or based on arguments passed to the constructor, set them in the constructor

Comment: I'd like to disagree with @YashParekh you can take a look at popular libraries and see that properties are set in the body instead of the __cosnstruct().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting variables on Constructor VS on the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484265/setting-variables-on-constructor-vs-on-the-class-definition)

Comment: I'd also definitely go with the second variant. Imho it's a lot cleaner plus it has meaning to doc-parsing tools like phpDocumentor.

Comment: Use second example - always, because on extending this class you can forget about vars in __construct that's why best solution is second one. It's all about OOP you are using and framework you are playing with.

Comment: _do the same way everywhere consistently_ The only right answer in my eyes. 100% eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To not violate [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) the easiest way to define the initial values would be as "default" values in constructor:

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    public function __construct(string $bar = 'default') {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }
}
```

Other viable approach is define the in the factory's or (more likely) DI container's configuration. With those options, you can also use separate setter to assign those predefined *defaults*.

If you really need to have specific values set in a class, you should assign them to `protected` parameters, but have those values aliased through constants.

That way you will be able to override them by extending the base class. And the constants will allow you (if there is no other way) to change the specific value of a default not just within a single class but in the entire codebase.